# Get presigned url of all objects in bucket amazon aws s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get pre-signed url of all object in bucket. I am using amazon php sdk **version 3**.

What I have tried is

```
$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'credentials.ini' => [
        'key' => $credentials['key'],
        'secret' => $credentials['secret'],
    ],
]);

$client->listObjects(['Bucket' => $bucketName]);
```

Above get me all object in arrayAccess but It have object url like

```
 https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some-demo/one2.txt
```

and I don't want that everyone have access to one2.txt so I have created a preassigned url by

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key
]);
$request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

echo $presignedUrl;
```

Now I am getting url with token

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some-demo/one2.txt?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJUZQHGPBTNOLEUXQ%2F20150828%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20150828T090256Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=Host&X-Amz-Expires=1200&X-Amz-Signature=77e52cf99c0f438d48851193dbaba0fsdfe1b4d8e604d6sdf11a22b3be45e410168ab81
```

which Is exactly what I want but Now my question is

**How to get preassigned url all items in bucket rather than making for all item one by one ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one way to get preassigned url of all items by creating an array of multiple getCommands, getCommand can handle [multiple commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-commands.html) and then you can use [toArray()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CommandInterface.html#_toArray) function of Aws\CommandInterface to convert it into an array. The [createPresignedRequest()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_createPresignedRequest) function does not support for multiple requests either you have to called it repetitive or need to use an [getObject()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObjectUrl)

Comment: can I use something like token to get those url ?

Comment: i am using version 3 api not 2